# Сортировка dom элементов с Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой вот список блоков, нужно, чтоб происходила сортировка по блоку s3 и меняла положение блока item (ну поднимало выше или ниже)

```
<div class='s'>
 <div class='item'>
     <div class='s1'>text</div>
     <div class='s2'>text</div>
     <div class='s3'>1232</div>
</div>
 <div class='item'>
     <div class='s1'>text</div>
     <div class='s2'>text</div>
     <div class='s3'>1232</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как это сделать? Просто с js я только в процессе изучения, а сделать такую хрень нужно сейчас. При попытки читать разные статьи кусками, в голове каша. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если вы хотите, чтоб с нуля написали, то могут и не написать - здесь не очень принято. если пишете, но что-то не понимаете или не получается, то с большой вероятностью подскажут.

Comment: значение числовое или может быть текст?

Comment: Нашел для себя плагин [TinySoft](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) он решил мою проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Надо вытащить все блоки в массив, отсортировать его по нужному параметру, и вставить обратно в DOM в новом порядке:

```js
var $el = $('#container')
  ,arr = $el.children().sort(
    function( a, b){
      a = parseInt( $('.s3', a).text(), 10);
      b = parseInt( $('.s3', b).text(), 10);
      return (a>b ? 1 : (a==b ? 0 : -1));
    }
  );

$el.append( arr);
```

```css
.item{border:1px solid #999; margin:10px;width:100px} .s3{background-color:#DDD}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='item'>
    <div class='s1'>s1 1200</div><div class='s2'>s2 1200</div><div class='s3'>1200</div>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <div class='s1'>s1 500</div><div class='s2'>s2 500</div><div class='s3'>500</div>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <div class='s1'>s1 1300</div><div class='s2'>s2 1300</div><div class='s3'>1300</div>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <div class='s1'>s1 700</div><div class='s2'>s2 700</div><div class='s3'>700</div>
  </div>
</div>
```